# Is there any sense defining a variable as protected in a trait?

Tags: scala, protected, traits

A trait cannot be instantiated. Hence, its fields can only be accessed by classes/traits/objects extending it. Hence, these two pieces of code are effectively the same:

```
trait foo{
    protected val fish:String
}
class bar extends foo{
    val fish = "catfish"
}
```

and

```
trait foo{
    val fish:String
}
class bar extends foo{
    val fish = "catfish"
}
```

The `protected`  access modifier is redundant for traits then. Right?

Comment: IMO if your using private and/or protected in Scala code it means your not really doing FP, your very much sticking to OOP.

Comment: @samthebest Yes, that is true. btw http://youryoure.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's redundant only because in the first version you've changed the visibility of the member from `protected` to `public` in the implementing class (by not marking it as `protected`). If you don't do that, then you can see that defining a member as `protected` in a trait means that a class has to implement it, *but* not expose it through its public API.

```
trait Foo {
  protected val fish: String
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  override protected val fish = "catfish"
}

val bar = new Bar
bar.fish // not visible
```

Comment: What if the trait has an implemented method `baz` and the classes extending the trait only use the method `baz`? We still need the protected modifier then?

Comment: No, but then you're exposing `baz` through the public interface. `protected` means "hide from outside users, but allow overriding when inherited".

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand when you say "exposing baz through the public interface."? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Core_Dumped I mean that when you instantiate a `new Bar`, you can't call the protected member, it's kind of private. Makes sense?